# How to assign different values to buttons in a listView - Android

Tags: android, listview, button, android-activity

I have a ListView Item that has 2 buttons in it. There are multiple ListView items so there are many buttons. How can I assign a different value to each button? What I want to happen is every button leads to the same activity, but when it goes to the new activity it sends a value that the button was assigned. Then the activity can handled the value. I want the values assigned to the buttons to be the same as what the text is set to, here is my baseAdapter

```
class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
            Context ctx_invitation;
            String[] listComments;
            String[] listNumbers;
            String[] listUsernames;


            public CreateCommentLists(String[] comments, String[] usernames, String[] numbers, DashboardActivity context)
            {
                super();
                ctx_invitation = context;
                listComments = comments;
                listNumbers = usernames;
                listUsernames = numbers;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                if(null == listComments)
                {
                return 0;
                }   

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments[position];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v = null;
                try
                {
                    String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
                    TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
                    TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);
                    Button usernameButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listUsernameButton);
                   Button numberButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumberButton);

                    commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
                    NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
                    usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
                    usernameButton.setText("Go to " + listUsernames[position]);
                    numberButton.setText("Go to " + listNumbers[position]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return v;
            }

          }
```

Comment: And your `Intent`? You can put extra values to the intent and read them in the launched activity.

Comment: but how do i do this?

Comment: Please post your intent :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usernameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("param", listUsernames[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: How do I retreive the param once the TargetActivity is created?

Comment: Also, I have tried this and it does not work, I want the param to be the usernames and it gives me an error when I try to do it.

Comment: add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); then override onNewIntent(Intent intent) method in TargetActivity, so you can get last intent.

Comment: you might need to do something like this in getView medthod: final String[] names = listUsernames; then use final variable names in OnClick method.